# Xcode C++ linker bug or missing setting ?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker

I got this a strange linker error.for my Xcode 7.3.1
I add the library libtbb.dylib to my C++ project under Build Phase->Link Binary with Libraries

When the linker launches, it adds the switch

```
-ltbb
```

instead of the expected

```
-libtbb
```

As a result, I get this link error:

```
ld: library not found for -ltbb clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How does this get fixed? Is there a setting I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: `-ltbb` is right; `-libtbb` is wrong. If the library is not found then it
is not present in any of the search directories you have specified to the
linker, or its defaults. As you haven't posted the failing linker command
we can't see which, if any, you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike Kingham, your hints was exactly it. Specify the library in the Build Phases-Link binary with library. You also need to specify the library search path under Build Settings as well.